# hyperHTML: generic content in a loop is always rendered full and lose it's bindings (click events)

Tags: ecmascript-6, hyperhtml

I have some problems by using hyperHTML (maybe only some understandings-problems).

When I have dynamic content in a loop, the content is fully rendered and lose it's bindings (like `document.body.innerHTML = content`, which is not the idea of hyperHTML, isn't it?). Please see my example below:

```js
function render() {
  console.log('render');
  
  hyperHTML.bind(document.body) `start:<br>
    ${[1,2,3].map(item => `
      count <button id="testbutton${item}">button${item}</button><br>
    `)}<br>
    press button2<br>
    <button id="testbutton">Test Button</button><br>
    last rendering ${new Date().toTimeString()}`;
}

function init() {
  render();
  let self = this;
  document.querySelector('#testbutton2').addEventListener('click', () => self.render());  
  document.querySelector('#testbutton').addEventListener('click', () => self.render());  
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => init());
```

```html
<script src="https://webreflection.github.io/hyperHTML/min.js"></script>
```

The first time `button2` is clicked the content is rendered. The initial binding is still working. After the content is rendered again the listener is lost.

On the other side, the `Test Button` is not rendered again. The binding is still present.

Could somebody explain me, how to use hypeHTML in a proper way by iterating over a list.

Thanks,
Matthias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In hyperHTML there are basically two utilities: *bind*, which renders content inside a node, and *wire*, which create content instead.

[image]

The wire method gives you the ability to relate its content to a specific object, and this is the missing bit of your snippet.

You are indeed simply returning an array of strings, and an Array as interpolation value, [as described in the documentation](https://viperhtml.js.org/hyperhtml/documentation/#essentials-8), is an explicit opt-in for html but it's just about dealing with strings, not DOM node.

You are also using that string as regular template literals, and not as hyperHTML content, because you are using interpolations in the wild, like inside attributes, which is not allowed in hyperHTML (read about partial attributes in the documentation).

To solve all these issues at once, you just need to wire either the same item, if that's an object, or a reference that won't change, like the hyperHTML container itself.

Since you want to relate inner content multiple times, all you need to do is to use an `:id` so that per N items you'll have N weak relationships.

I have [created a Code Pen example](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/RLWwOG) that shows all this through very few changes to your original code.

Comment: Hi Andrea,
thanks you very much for your feedback and your great example at Code Pen. Now it's clear :-)

Comment: https://codepen.io/janat08/pen/wpWgbO
I  tried changing the array before each update, no good came out of it.